# Repeat Callers - Power BI Measure or Calculated Column?

Tags: powerbi

I have a database of call details and need to get a count of calls that are repeat callers within a 2 day time frame.
[Picture of columns in DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK4Jl.png)

I have attempted this in a couple different ways.

Calculated Column -

```
RC1 = 
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(CallDetails),
    FILTER(CallDetails,
        CallDetails[Customer ID]=EARLIER(CallDetails[Customer ID]) &&
        CallDetails[Call Start Date]>=DATEADD(CallDetails[Call Start Date],2,day)))
```

Measure -

```
RC2 = 
CALCULATE(CallDetails[Incoming Call Count],
    FILTER( ALLEXCEPT(CallDetails,CallDetails[Customer ID])
    ,CallDetails[Call Start Date]<=DATEADD(CallDetails[Call Start Date],2,day)
   )
)
```

Neither have been correct and I have reached the end of my knowledge in DAX so far.  How can this be done?

Comment: I notice that you're basing your calculations on `Call ID`, but isn't this unique to the call? Shouldn't you instead be calculating using `Customer ID`?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  I am calculating based on the customer ID in my original, but when I transferred it here and adjusted column names to help describe my question, I made that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `measure`:

```
RC1 =
VAR T1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CallDetails,
        "Count",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( CallDetails ),
                FILTER (
                    CallDetails,
                    CallDetails[Customer ID] = EARLIER ( CallDetails[Customer ID] )
                        && ABS ( CallDetails[Call Start Date] - EARLIER ( CallDetails[Call Start Date] ) ) <= 2
                )
            )
    )
VAR T2 =
    GROUPBY (
        T1,
        CallDetails[Customer ID],
        "MaxCount", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [Count] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( T2, 0 + ( [MaxCount] > 1 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to look at this!

Please check to see if I understand this correctly.
T1 is a newly created virtual table that puts a 1 in the “count” column for each row that… 
1. Contains a cust ID that is listed earlier in the DB AND
2. Has a call start date +/- 2 days from the individual start date from each record (based upon the ABS before the calculation)
T2 then groups T1 by cust ID adding a column “MaxCount” that contains the maximum value for each cust ID.
The measure is then providing a sum at the row level of T2 only if “MaxCount” is greater than 2.

Comment: Your breakdown is spot on, apart from 2 points. T1 does not put "a 1 in the “count” column for each row that..."; the entry could be (and most likely will in some cases) more than 1. "Contains a cust ID that is listed earlier in the DB" - EARLIER doesn't actually refer to prior rows only, but to all other rows.

Comment: Oh, and "only if “MaxCount” is greater than 2" isn't correct either. You'll see that it's actually calculating for MaxCount greater than 1.